# Ejercicio básico en C: transponer matriz utilizando aritmética de punteros

Tags: c, punteros, matrices

Cargo la matriz secuencialmente y le asigno un orden a gusto.

La función que he hecho no muestra lo deseado:

```
void transpuesta(int *mat ,int orden)
{
    int i,j,aux;

    for(i=0;i<=orden;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=orden;j++){

            aux= *(mat+i*orden+j);
            *(mat+i*orden+j)=*(mat+j*orden+i);
            *(mat+j*orden+i)=aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Estoy intentando utilizar aritmética de punteros, pero no veo qué debería modificar para obtener la matriz traspuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, la solución sería esta:

```
void transpuesta(int *mat ,int orden)
{
    int i,j,aux;

    for(i=0;i<orden;i++){
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){


                aux= *(mat+i*orden+j);
                *(mat+i*orden+j)=*(mat+j*orden+i);
                *(mat+j*orden+i)=aux;
                }

                }
}
```